# Refactoring a python function so that it can take any sized list

Tags: python, refactoring

How can I make this function take as input an arbitrary list size?

```
def ugly_function(lst):
    for a in lst[0]:
        for b in lst[1]:
            for c in lst[2]:
                for d in lst[3]:
                    for e in lst[4]:
                        for f in lst[5]:
                            for g in lst[6]:
                                for h in lst[7]:
                                    if some_test([a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h]): 
                                        return [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h]
```

Comment: Wait... what? What are you trying to do?

Comment: i guessed that it's meant to return the first permutation that passes a predicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Check out `itertools`.](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

```
def ugly_function(lst):
   for comb in itertools.product(*lst):
      if some_test(comb):
          return comb
```

(Or, as a 1-liner:

```
def ugly_function(lst):
    return next(comb for comb in itertools.product(*lst) if some_test(comb))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from itertools import ifilter, product

def nice_function(lst):
    return ifilter(some_test, product(*lst)).next()
```

Comment: I voted this up but now I'm not sure it's what the OP wants. I think he wants `product` not `permutations`.

Comment: The OP has a cross-product, not permutations

Comment: i didn't see it but replacing `permutations(lst)` with `product(*lst)` is what is needed